# Using a case inside a different case

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would need to use "Case 2" inside "case 3", but everytime i do that, it doesn't work. 
Can someone help me? 
I don't know if I did something wrong inside the code or whatever..

I hope some of you can help me out.

The code i'm currently using:

```
case 2:
    Console.WriteLine("Gekozen actie: 2. Gegevens MP3 speler opslaan");
    Console.WriteLine("Type de ID: ");
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Type de Maker: ");
    string MAKE = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Type de Model : ");
    var MODEL = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Type de MBGrootte: ");
    int MBSize = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Type de Prijs: ");
    var PRICE = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());                                
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Ingevoerde gegevens: " +
        Environment.NewLine + "Uw ID: " + id +
        Environment.NewLine + "Uw Maker: " + MAKE +
        Environment.NewLine + "Uw Model: " + MODEL +
        Environment.NewLine + "Uw MBGrootte: " + MBSize +
        Environment.NewLine + "Uw Prijs: " + PRICE);
    Console.ReadLine();

    break;

case 3:
    Console.WriteLine("ID: 1" +
        Environment.NewLine + "Make: Get Technologies .inc" +
        Environment.NewLine + "Model: HF 410" +
        Environment.NewLine + "MBSize: 4096" +
        Environment.NewLine + "Price: $129.95");
    Console.ReadLine();

    break;
```

(I need "CASE 2" Below in "CASE 3" (under Console.ReadLine())   Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: I see that the code isn't paste correctly inside the grey block, but the part above it is also inside the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case 2:
case 3:

if (yourVar == 3)
{
  Console.WriteLine("ID: 1" + Environment.NewLine + 
      "Make: Get Technologies .inc" + Environment.NewLine +
      "Model: HF 410" + Environment.NewLine +
      "MBSize: 4096" + Environment.NewLine + "Price: $129.95");

  Console.ReadLine();    
}

Console.WriteLine("Gekozen actie: 2. Gegevens MP3 speler opslaan");
Console.WriteLine("Type de ID: ");
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Type de Maker: ");
string MAKE = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Type de Model : ");
var MODEL = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Type de MBGrootte: ");
int MBSize = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Type de Prijs: ");
var PRICE = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Ingevoerde gegevens: " +
Environment.NewLine + "Uw ID: " + id +
Environment.NewLine + "Uw Maker: " + MAKE +
Environment.NewLine + "Uw Model: " + MODEL +
Environment.NewLine + "Uw MBGrootte: " + MBSize +
Environment.NewLine + "Uw Prijs: " + PRICE);
Console.ReadLine();
break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your `Case 2` inside a method, and then use this method in `Case 2` and `Case 3`

Comment: I got it inside a Switch. Like this:
int choice =01;
    if (int.TryParse(ans, out choice))
    
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine("Gekozen actie: 1. Overzicht MP3 Spelers");
                            Console.WriteLine("Druk op enter om het menu af te sluiten");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            break;